# onTouch override - error message in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I'm using code like the below to implement a multi-touch pinch in an Android app. I saw code examples just like this one several times on the web, so I was puzzled to find that Eclipse constantly gives me a "**The method onTouch(View, MotionEvent) of type Touch must override a superclass method**" error message here and won't let me execute the code.  The build target is Android 2.1, the image resource exists, the manifest file looks good, etc.

Does anybody have an idea why Eclipse might be flagging an error here?

```
package org.example.touch;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Touch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

**@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)** {
  return true;   }

}
```

Comment: I've copied that in to Eclipse, no errors. Weird. Try a clean and build.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing Project | Properties | JavaCompiler to 1.6. Before 1.6 it doesn't allow using @Overrides on interface methods.

(I think you can safely use 1.6 level btw, Java 1.6 may not be supported for building Android source code (meaning it won't build with this setting) but as for building applications it works fine and I've never seen 'use 1.5' notice. Of course it's a philosophical question whether we indeed @Override interface methods or not and we need not to dwell deeply into this question for practical purposes)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you imported the listener,

```
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
```

at the top of your file with the other imports.

Answer (score 0):

Android is built on Java 5 standards from the start, and (as the previous answer says) Java 5 does not support @Override annotations on methods implementing Interface methods, only on methods overriding superclass methods.

While setting the Java compiler settings in Eclipse to 1.6 allows you to do this, my personal opinion is that keeping (or setting) your compiler setting at 1.5 and removing the annotation is the way to go.

I realize that it's not directly connected to writing stand-alone Android applications, but the [Android source page](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/opensource/download) says explicitely:

> JDK 5.0, update 12 or higher.  Java 6 is not supported, because of incompatibilities with @Override.

Comment: Appreciate the comment.  I'll try to figure out how to make this work.